# How to remove % from end of url in apache rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've noticed an increase of requested URLs with a `%` at the end.
eg. `http://sample.com/countries/usa%`

We have an Apache rewrite rule the converts a properly formed request to the desired page on the server

```
RewriteRule ^countries/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /index.php?c=$2
```

However, when the user (or a bot?) adds the `%` symbol to the end it forces a `400` error.
Google's Webmaster Tools has found an increase of these type of errors and I haven't a clue how to remove it.  I can't do it in PHP because the error is happening at the Apache level.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would add something like this in the beginning of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This causes a **permanent** redirect (because of R=301) to the page without the '%'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That isn't working for me.  Does it matter where in the sequence to put it?  I'm not an apache expert, but with the L after the rewrite, doesn't that tell it to stop looking for more rules?

Comment: @user2431427 You should put it as the first rule. If someone visits your site with a % added, this RewriteRule will be taken. It will cause a redirect, so this has to be the last rule.
After the redirect your .htaccess will be parsed again.

Comment: @user2431427 I forgot to escape the % sign. (adding the \ before %) Try with the edited rule.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I tried with the escape and even removed all other rewrite rules, and i still get "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."  when the url has a get variable that ends with %.

Comment: @user2431427 It seems that this problem can not be solved with a RewriteRule. Thus, this solution makes no sense. Maybe you have a misformatted URL somewhere in your HTML code?